# Cannot ping Ubuntu from another device on the same network

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dns, ping

I have downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 on my Windows laptop. The problem is that I cannot ping the Ubuntu app from another device on the same network, except the host machine.

**What I've done so far:**

- Disabled Firewalls
- Allowed ICMP
- Changed Network profile type to Private

Here's the **ipconfig** of the laptop:

```
    Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::db15:8303:d9ea:939c%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.5
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9e5a:3463:cc2e:55fd%39
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.96.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

**Ubuntu** `ip addr`:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:15:5d:c7:d3:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.22.109.12/20 brd 172.22.111.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fec7:d3ac/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Ubuntu** `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.22.96.1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your output does not seem to show the client's attempt to connect. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1485090/edit) to clearly show how you determined that the client and the server are really on the same network.

Comment: *"The problem is that I cannot ping the Ubuntu app from another device on the same network, except the host machine."* - That is correct because WSL runs on a virtual networking device and is not exposed directly to your network so unless you find a way in Windows to bridge that connection there is no way that you will be able to ping that IP address of WSL.

Comment: You might want to see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#connecting-via-remote-ip-addresses